# When a method is executed in a thread. Does it also calls the (default/parameterized) constructor

Tags: c#, threadpool

When a method is executed in a thread. Does it also calls the (default/parameterized) constructor of the class containing that method before calling the method.

```
public class Class1
{
    HttpContext h = null;
    public Class1(HttpContext _h)
    {
        h = _h;
    }
    public Class1()
    {
        if (h != null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current = h;
        }
    }
    ManualResetEvent[] wsManualResetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[1];

    public void callThread()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ok"] = "ll";
        wsManualResetEvents[0] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(o => me()));
        if (wsManualResetEvents != null && wsManualResetEvents[0] != null)
        {
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(wsManualResetEvents);
        }
    }
    private void me()
    {
        var d = HttpContext.Current.Session["ok"].ToString();
        wsManualResetEvents[0].set();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do, is to set the httpcontext of the thread equivalent to the executing thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, starting a thread does not call the constructor. In the case of your code, you have an instance of `Class1` and you're calling `.callThread()` on it. When `me()` is invoked on the background thread, it's calling `me()` on the same instance of `Class1`. Just because you've started a new thread doesn't mean you've created a new `Class1` object.

Comment: we have a lot of things going into session and threads manipulate session variables a lot. So we end up passing httpcontext as a parameter to the thread method and setting the httpcontext.current = http_context_from_parameter.